# Is it possible to use ColorChecker Passport with Film?

Tags: film, color-management, colorchecker

The software for the X-Rite ColorChecker Passport seem to only work with DNG.  Is it possible to use this with scanned film?  I tried converting TIFF and JPEG scans to DNG but X-Rite's program just says it can't understand the DNG.

As a note I am scanning with an Epson V850.

Comment: You can convert these to DNG... Use Adobe DNG Converter or export the image from Lightroom into DNG.

Comment: I tried that as stated in the question.

Comment: Did you try both method?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Did you create a version using Adobe DNG Converter, and another using Lightroom's DNG exporter? Did you experience the same error response from the X-Rite software?

Comment: I used DNG export on a trial copy of Lightroom.  I will see about using the DNG converter directly.

Comment: You could try Vuescan, this software can scan RAW DNG files. Besides the userinterface it's a highly professional software.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same situation going on now. Except I'm using the V550

Comment: You might save the image as a tiff, without compression then convert to DNG. Adobe's CC DNG CC profiler assumes a RAW image but that might be the closest. Not good odds but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try the Adobe DNGProfile Editor?

For camera but not a scanner, this work flow is work:

1, Export it to .DNG files.

2, Import it into DNGProfile Editor.

3, Align the chart table as in 'chart' tag (fig.1):
[image: fig.1]

4, Export it into a *.dcp profile.

5, Move this file into profile folder.
For windows:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\CameraProfiles\*.dcp
```

After all, you can apply it in ACR.

If you are not satisfied with this approach, it is possible to manually adjust it in HSL panel just like the SpyderCheckr24 do (this kind of color checker exports the adjustment of HSL). Or in color tables in DNG Editor (recommended).

In fact, I suppose the reason of your failure is because of the negetive appearance and colour cast which may not compatible with programmes. Only manual operation will work if you can't generate a positive version of **RAW files**.

(Personally, I suggest the correction of scanner is more important with the positive apperance)